# GraphView edge filter is same as original Graph after vertex filtering

Tags: python, graph-tool

I have a `Graph` and an associated edge property. I then filter the graph with a vertex filter with a `GraphView`.

```py
g = Graph(directed=False)
g.add_vertex(6)
g.add_edge_list([(0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)])
eprop = g.new_edge_property('int')
eprop.a = numpy.random.randint(0, 10, g.num_edges())

vfilt = g.new_vertex_property('bool')
vfilt.a[[0, 1, 2, 4]] = True
h = GraphView(g, vfilt=vfilt)
```

In this example, the original graph has 6 vertices and 6 edges as expected.

```
<Graph object, undirected, with 6 vertices and 6 edges at 0x1f9149550>
```

The view has 4 vertices and 4 edges.

```
<GraphView object, undirected, with 4 vertices and 4 edges, edges filtered by (<PropertyMap object with key type 'Edge' and value type 'bool', for Graph 0x209b4f7f0, at 0x182ea70f0>, False), vertices filtered by (<PropertyMap object with key type 'Vertex' and value type 'bool', for Graph 0x209b4f7f0, at 0x14a00a710>, False) at 0x209b4f7f0>
```

My ultimate objective is to get the values of `eprop` for the edges that exist in `h`. An easy and quick way to do this would be to use boolean array indexing on `eprop.a`. I thought that I would be able to use the view's edge filter for this, but it doesn't behave as I expected.

`h.get_edge_filter()` returns a `PropertyMap`

```
(<PropertyMap object with key type 'Edge' and value type 'bool', for Graph 0x209b4f7f0, at 0x182ea70f0>,
 False)
```

but `h.get_edge_filter()[0].a` shows that all the values are `True`

```
PropertyArray([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=uint8)
```

Am I doing something wrong here or expecting behaviour that I shouldn't?

Is there a faster way to get the edge property values for all the edges between a set of vertices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is expected for filtered graphs. The `.a` attribute always returns the underlying array, which contains also the unfiltered values. To access only the filtered values, you should use the `.fa` attribute instead.

This is explained in the documentation here: https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/graph_tool.html#graph_tool.PropertyMap.fa